# How does this trigonometric process work?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I am currently learning about hyperbolic functions, and I have been presented with the following:$$\sinh^2 x = \frac{\cosh2 x - 1}{2}$$

This may seem like a simple conversion for some, and my apologies for my ignorance on the topic; however, I do not know where to start with this. If someone could please explain to me the process from "a" to "b" I would be extremely grateful.

Comment: It's false. $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x=1$.

Comment: it means $$\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1$$

Comment: which identity do you mean Martin?

Comment: By definition of hyperbolic sine $\displaystyle \sinh x=\frac {e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ and hyperbolic cosine $\displaystyle \cosh x=\frac {e^{x}+e^{-x}}{2}$ square sides and simplify $\cosh^2x-\sinh^2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity should be $$\sinh^2 x = \frac{\cosh 2x -1}{2}.$$

Probably the easiest way to show it is by changing to exponential form:

$$\sinh^2 x = \left(\frac{e^x - e^{-x}}{2}\right)^2  = \frac{e^{2x} -2 +e^{-2x}}{4} = \frac{(e^{2x}+e^{-2x})/2-1}{2}  =\frac{\cosh 2x -1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

In the question you made a small mistake. There is no $2$ in the denominator of its right hand  side. By a small arithmetical confusion the $2$ of $\sinh$, $\cosh$ had gotten  forcefully forward.

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\sinh(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$ and $$\cosh(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$
plugging this in the term $$2\sinh(x)^2-\cosh(x)^2+1=\sinh(x)^2$$